# Haystack can't find any results

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-haystack

I am new to [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) and I just installed it with [Whoosh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/).

`base.py`

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'whoosh_index'),
    },
}
```

My Announcement model (located in the `posts` app):

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField('Announcement description',
                                   null=True, max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(default=uuid.uuid1, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name='posts',
                               null=True, blank=True)
```

So I built my index file named `search_indexes.py` placed inside the `posts` app.

```
class AnnouncementIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr="title")
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr="description")
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='author')
    status = indexes.BooleanField(model_attr='status')

    def get_model(self):
        return Announcement

    def index_queryset(self, using=Announcement):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(status=False)
```

My search view and form are not placed in the `posts` app, they are in the app named `homepages`.
This is the form `homepages/forms.py`:

```
class PostsSearchForm(SearchForm):

    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.all()
```

And the view `homepages/views.py`:

```
def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        current_user = request.user
        form = PostsSearchForm(request.GET)
        posts = None
        if form.data != {} and form.is_valid():
            posts = form.search()
            return render_to_response('search/search.html', {
                'posts': posts,
                'form': form
            })
```

The template with the form is in the `templates/homepages/home.html` file:

```
        <form method="GET">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form.q }}
        </form>
```

And I do have the the file `templates/searches/indexes/posts/announcement_text.txt`:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.description }}
```

Comment: Have you ran update_index command? http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/management_commands.html

Comment: Yep, and it told me that 1 announcement was indexed(I created just one for test).

Comment: Does the `Announcement` model have a `status` field? I don't see one in the model you have posted above, and without it things would break.